# How to compare two DateTime columns Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, comparison

I have a column where I insert a date when the event happens (storage locally), and the date when the event is send to my system.

The difference between the event date and the send date can not be more than 168h (7 days).

I would like to select all rows where the event data + 168h is lower than the send data.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM SALE
WHERE (DAT_SALE + 168HOUR) < DAT_SEND_SALE;
```

Comment: may be the better way is to use INTERVAL for your case

Comment: Oracle does not have a `DateTime` data type - it has `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` and they both have a time component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an `interval`

```
SELECT * 
FROM sale
WHERE (dat_sale + interval '168' HOUR) < dat_end_sale;
```

Alternatively you can simply use the 7 days:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sale
WHERE (dat_sale + 7) < dat_end_sale;
```

When adding (or subtracting) an integer to a `date` or `timestamp` that number implicitly the number of days.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that if you add a number (not necessarily an integer) to a timestamp the result is a date, so you lose any fractional seconds or time zone info; which may or may not matter...